# Wildfly 8.1 compatibility with Openjdk

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8

I am using Widlfly 8.1 on production with JDK 8. I would like to update JDk to latest OpenJdk version.

Could you please tell me Wildfly 8.1 compatibility with latest Openjdk version?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Getting Started Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Getting%20Started%20Guide.html):

> Requirements
>
> Java SE 7 or later (we recommend that you use the latest update
> available)

Having said that I would stick with a LTS release (Java 8 or Java 11) as the sub releases don't get as thorough of testing (from the [Wildfly 18 release notes, JDK 13 section](https://www.wildfly.org/news/2019/10/03/WildFly18-Final-Released/)):

> While we do want to run well on the most recent JDK, our
> recommendation is that you run WildFly on the most recent long-term
> support release, i.e. on JDK 11 for WildFly 18. We do considerably
> more testing of WildFly itself on the LTS JDKs, and we make no attempt
> to ensure the projects producing the various libraries we integrate
> are testing their libraries on anything other than JDK 8 or 11.
>
> WildFly 18 also is heavily tested and runs well on Java 8. We plan to continue to support Java 8 at least through WildFly 21, and
> probably beyond.

I have been running Wildfly on OpenJDK versions for a year plus now and have had zero issues.

Comment: If I understood you right and read the documentation It means that Wildfly 8.1 is compatible with JDK 11 or OpenJDK 12. Am I understood you right.

Comment: Yes though, again, I'd encourage OpenJDK 11. If you take a look at the [version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history) you'll see that OpenJDK 12 hasn't been supported for over a year.  Pick a LTS (currently 8 or 11) and use that.  The intermediate versions are for new features that you may not need yet.